# How to Get All Facebook Post of a page using Php?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am working on   to get `Facebook` page info . I am  geting information of a Facebook page .  It is simple to get information about one post. How can I get all post and comments for that page?

I am using access key to get info. However PHP has some execution time after that execution time it will not execute the remaining code. So, if the Facebook page has 1000 post's it will take lot of time.

How can I get all posts and comments?  I am having the same problem problem with `Google+, Instagram, Pinterest, YouTube and twitter` as well .

```
public static function getFacebookData($post_url) {
        $facebook_token = Yii::app()->params['media_key_api']['facebook']['facebook_access_token'];
        //split url to get pagename
        $url = explode('?', $post_url);
        $split_url = explode('/', $url[0]);
        $facebook_post_id = end($split_url);
        $facebook_page_name = $split_url[3];

        $page_url = $split_url[0] . '//' . $split_url[1] . '/' . $split_url[2] . '/' . $split_url[3];

        //hit URL to get page info
        $facebook_page = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook_page_name . '?access_token=' . $facebook_token;

        $facebook_page_data = self::get_curl_data($facebook_page, true);

    }
```

Comment: show your code, how are you fetching posts from facebook ?

Comment: to fetch posts you will have to do: `https://graph.facebook.com/business_name/posts?access_token=xxxxxxx`, and then loop through the `paging`'s `next` value

Comment: yes i know that but if there is a post more than 1000 it take too much time to execute i want to reduce that time .

Comment: yes, it will take some time I don't think there is another way, if you want to store 1000 posts and its comments then obviously you will have to deal with the execution time, additionally you could pass a limit `https://graph.facebook.com/business_name/posts?access_token=xxxxxxx&limit=100`

Comment: i am thinking that i will store 100 post first then after that i will use cron to store remaining post . Is this way will be  good ?